# Cannot switch to jenkins user redhat linux

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, user, jenkins

I have a redhat linux server running jenkins. I setup jenkins as per the instructions mentioned here https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions The problem is that I need to switch to the jenkins user in order to solve an ssh connection issue, but I cannot.

I try

```
su - jenkins
```

however after I enter that, the terminal remains`[root@redhat ~]#` and a `whoami` reveals that I am still `root` I have looked at the files `/etc/passwd  etc/shadow` and see that jenkins is a user, but I don't have enough experience to tell what I have done wrong in setting up this jenkins user.

any ideas would be helpful, or places to look for clues?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

is jenkins a service account with no shell configured in `/etc/password`  If that's it try
`sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins`

Comment: That's the way! Now for anyone that has similar problems /var/lib/jenkins acts as the home dir for jenkins user and will have .ssh

Comment: You could also run `sudo -u jenkins bash`

Answer (score 1):

Do not change the /etc/passwd file. The interactive login is set to false for a good reason, the list security implications is too long to describe here.

Instead, run this as root:

```
sudo su - jenkins -s /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to change the shell for jenkins.

Run the below command:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Now you will be able to switch as jenkins user by just passing `su jenkins`

Comment: Do not do this.  the account lacks a shell for good reason - service accounts shouldn't be able to log in interactively.  This is a security risk with no real benefit.